# Martingale associated to Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, martingales

$X$ is a (continuous time) Markov chain with generator matrix $\Lambda$ and finite state space $G$.  I know that for $g\colon G \to R$
$$ M_t = g(X_t) - g(X_0) - \int_0^t (\Lambda g)(X_s)\, ds $$ is a martingale. Is it obvious how to extend this to $f\colon[0,T] \times G \to R$  where $f$ is $C^1$ wrt $t$ i.e. to show that 
$$ M_t = f(t,X_t) - f(0,X_0) - \int_0^t \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(u, X_u) +(\Lambda f)(u,X_u)\right)\, du $$ is also a martingale? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe we have to assume some boundedness condition on $f$ and its derivative. This result is on Landim's book about particle systems.

Comment: $f$ is bounded since continuous in $t$ and $G$ is finite. Thanks for the reference, will try to find it.

Answer (score 2):

If this is still of interest, such process can be represented as a PDMP (piecewise-deterministic Markov process) with time being one of the states. In [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/041231410X) M. Davis gives an **explicit** characterization of the extended generator of a PDMP together with its domain - i.e. you will find both necessary and sufficient conditions on $f$.

Answer (score 0):

We have to show that for all $t\geqslant s$,
$$E[M_t\mid\mathcal F_s]=M_s.$$
For $u,v\in\Bbb R$, write $g_u(v):=f(u,v)$. We have to show, introducing the semi-group $\{P_t\}$, that 
\begin{align}g_t(X_t)-g_s(X_s)&=\int_s^tP_{u-s}(\partial_u f(u,X_u)+(\Lambda f)(u,X_u))du\\
&=\int_0^{t-s}P_v(\partial_v g_{v+s}(X_{v+s})+(\Lambda f)(v+s,X_{v+s}))dv.
\end{align}
So it reduces to show equality between the derivatives. Let $h\neq 0$. Then 
\begin{align}
f(t+h,X_{t+h})-f(t,X_t)&=f(t+h,X_{t+h})-f(t+h,X_t)+f(t+h,X_t)-f(t,X_t)\\
&=(P_h-I)g_{t+h}(X_t)+f(t+h,X_t)-f(t,X_t).
\end{align}
We conclude using the definition of $\Lambda$ and the continuity of the semi-group.